# ASP.NET NHibernate C# Timeout Issue SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, nhibernate, timeout

I'm running a website using ASP.NET and NHibernate. Recently the website has been running into an issue where it causes a SQL Server Timeout issue. I've come to discover that the issue is related to an NHibernate Query that is locking down a table in the database. The website will recover after 20 minutes or if I manually force all connections on the database to end.

Basically I've been trying to find which query is causing this issue, but unfortunately after many months of trying to find the Query using NHibernate profiler, I've had no success. The issue occurs very rarely, usually only 1 - 2 times a week, which is making it even more difficult to figure out what causes the query that locks down the table. I have .net setup to send me error logs when they occur, this has helped me avoid the site from being locked down when they query is run because I am able to force all SQL connections to drop, then the site is restored.

Long story short, what I need is a band-aid solution, something that will temporarily work for the site while I continue to try to find the bad query. What I want to do is change the timeout time from 20 minutes to something like 2 - 5 minutes. That way it limits how long the site will be down when this bad query is run. Considering that the bad query only happens 1 - 2 times a week I fiqured this would be limited downtime.

The only problem is I don't know if this is something SQL Server is imposing or if this is something .net or NHibernate is imposing. Basically what I am referring to is the 20 minutes that the connection is finally dropped after the bad query is run. Anyone know what this 20 minutes is and where it can be set? I'm leaning towards this probably being an NHibernate timeout of some sort, but I don't know how to set it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that is 20 min is the idle-timeout setting on the application pool the site runs under. So after 20 min of inactivity IIS will recycle the whole worker process and everything works again. So you can change this setting on the application pool to 2-5 min.

Now, from what you are saying it looks like you are not disposing a transaction properly and it runs until a timeout. So what you need to do to identify what code is attach with a debugger to the IIS website and look at the threads to see where are they stuck.

[This](http://vimeo.com/9936296) is a bit advanced but if you follow along you will be able to see what is locking your database. If you have visual studio on the IIS server it will be easier as the debugging environment is more familiar.

Comment: Could this be happening if I am caching an domain object that is mapped to a table in the database? I was thinking about it and a major change I made when this first started happening was storing a site object in cache so it doesn't have to go back to the table to retrieve it. But could that somehow be preventing it from disposing of the transaction?

Comment: First, are you using transactions with NHibernate? If yes, make sure that are in a using statement or that you are disposing them properly. Every Session.BeginTransaction() must have a corresponding Dispose(). I guess if you post some code would be useful. Where do you open your sessions? is it the code behind or in the BeginRequest event?